# One exception is caught twice by the NetBeans platform

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, platform

Hi i´m development and app with Netbeans Platform and i can´t catch this exception:

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

I use the follow line:

```
       try { 
           il.delete(lote);

       }
       catch (HibernateException he) {
           NotifyDescriptor error = new NotifyDescriptor.Message(ERROR+he.getMessage(), NotifyDescriptor.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           DialogDisplayer.getDefault().notify(error);
       }
```

My interface may throw this exception, and the exception can be captured in the TopComponent. The problem is that I get twice, one is my notification and another from the platform.
How I can fix this?

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1):

In case of above code there is no possibility that you will receive exception twice. Because there is only one method call which returns exception.
What might possibility is you might be requesting it two times so that you are receiving exception multiple times.

What you can do is add a log check if method is being called multiple times on single click and fix that issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not upload the image, but the notifications I get are different, one is DialogDisplayer mia, and the other is the native platform,

Comment: export jar file from netbeans and execute code from outside this behavior may be specific to NetBeans.